# What is the purpose of the 'tracking.contact' MongoDB database?

Tags: xdb, aggregation

Sitecore XP version `8.0`, `8.1` and `8.2` comes with following MongoDB databases:

- `analytics`
- `tracking.live`
- `tracking.history`
- `tracking.contact`

What is the purpose of the `tracking.contact' database in MongoDB?

Answer (score 6):

### Tracking Contact

The `tracking.contact`database is used by one entity only:

- *Contact Processing Pool* (defined in the `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.ProcessingPools.config` file).

#### Contact Processing Pool

It works with the `ProcessingPool` collection  that is defined in the `tracking.contact` database. Whenever a contact is changed (created, updated or became obsolete), a new work item with a Contact ID is added to the contact processing pool for future processing.

The *Processing / Aggregation* role runs the *Contact Processing* agent (defined in the `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.Services.config` file). The agent uses the *Contact Work Dispatcher* (defined in the `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.Services.config` file) to get work items from the contact processing pool. Each work item is processed by calling the `analytics.aggregation/contacts` pipeline.